# How to get the name from a mixed struct to save to Firebase

Tags: arrays, database, struct

I'm fairly new at using structs and search functions. In my tableView, I have a list of vegetables which you can checkmark. Now I want to be able to save the `name` checkmarked veggies in my firebase. I tried some solutions online but I'm getting an error.

This is the code that I'm trying to fix.

```
struct TypeOfVeggie {
    let veggieName: String
    var checkmarked: Bool
}

var veggies = [TypeOfVeggie(veggieName: "Carrots", checkmarked: false), TypeOfVeggie(veggieName: "Letuce", checkmarked: false), TypeOfVeggie(veggieName: "Tomato", checkmarked: false), TypeOfVeggie(veggieName: "Pickle", checkmarked: false)]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isSearching {
        filteredVeggies[indexPath.row].checkmarked.toggle()
        let index = veggies.firstIndex{$0.name == filteredVeggies[indexPath.row].name}!
        veggies[index].checkmarked.toggle()
    } else {
        veggies[indexPath.row].checkmarked.toggle()
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    }

 @IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let checkedVeggies = veggies.filter{$0.isChecked} // do i use || or &&

    let UserDictionary : [String:Any] =
        ["Veggie List": checkedVeggies]

Database.database().reference().child("User").child(currentUID!).updateChildValues(UserDictionary)

}
```

I want to be able to save the `checkmarked` name(String) of the veggies in Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you want an array of names rather than an array of `TypeOfVeggie` map the array: `let checkedVeggies = veggies.filter{$0.checkedMarked}.map{$0.name}`. this answer came from another developer